# Unity inside React JS: Magic header problem

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, webgl, webassembly, unity-webgl

I'm trying to insert a build unity of type WebGL in the react JS application. However, I am having a problem with the file called WASM (WebAssembly) provided by Unity. My purpose is to show the game on the webpage. NOTE: If there are easier solutions, I'm receptive.

**My Code:**

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import buildUrlLoader from "../UnityGames/BuildWebGl3/Build/BuildWebGl3.loader.js";
import buildUrlData from "../UnityGames/BuildWebGl3/Build/BuildWebGl3.data";
import buildUrlFramework from "../UnityGames/BuildWebGl3/Build/BuildWebGl3.framework.js"; 
import buildUrlWasm from "../UnityGames/BuildWebGl3/Build/BuildWebGl3.wasm";

function Component1() {
      
   useEffect(() => {
   // var buildUrl = "Build";
    var loaderUrl = buildUrlLoader ;// buildUrl + "/BuildWebGl3.loader.js";
    var config = {
      dataUrl: buildUrlData, //buildUrl + "/BuildWebGl3.data",
      frameworkUrl: buildUrlFramework, // buildUrl + "/BuildWebGl3.framework.js",
      codeUrl: buildUrlWasm, // buildUrl + "/BuildWebGl3.wasm",
      streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
      companyName: "DefaultCompany",
      productName: "My project (1)",
      productVersion: "1.0",
    };

    var container = document.querySelector("#unity-container");
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#unity-canvas");
    var loadingBar = document.querySelector("#unity-loading-bar");
    //var progressBarFull = document.querySelector("#unity-progress-bar-full");
    //var fullscreenButton = document.querySelector("#unity-fullscreen-button");
    var mobileWarning = document.querySelector("#unity-mobile-warning");

    if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
      container.className = "unity-mobile";
      config.devicePixelRatio = 1;
      mobileWarning.style.display = "block";
      setTimeout(() => {
        mobileWarning.style.display = "none";
      }, 5000);
    } else {
      canvas.style.width = "960px";
      canvas.style.height = "600px";
    }
    loadingBar.style.display = "block";

    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = loaderUrl;
    // script.onload = () => {
    //    createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
    //     progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
    //   }).then((unityInstance) => {
    //     loadingBar.style.display = "none";
    //     fullscreenButton.onclick = () => {
    //       unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
    //     };
    //   }).catch((message) => {
    //     alert(message);
    //   });
    // };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.async = true;      
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, []);

  return( 
    <div>
     
     <div id="unity-container" class="unity-desktop">
      <canvas id="unity-canvas"></canvas>
      <div id="unity-loading-bar">
        <div id="unity-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-progress-bar-empty">
          <div id="unity-progress-bar-full"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="unity-mobile-warning">
        WebGL builds are not supported on mobile devices.
      </div>
      <div id="unity-footer">
        <div id="unity-webgl-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-fullscreen-button"></div>
        <div id="unity-build-title">My project (1)</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  );
}
export default Component1;
```

**Original Unity HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Unity WebGL Player | My project (1)</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="TemplateData/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="TemplateData/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="unity-container" class="unity-desktop">
      <canvas id="unity-canvas"></canvas>
      <div id="unity-loading-bar">
        <div id="unity-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-progress-bar-empty">
          <div id="unity-progress-bar-full"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="unity-mobile-warning">
        WebGL builds are not supported on mobile devices.
      </div>
      <div id="unity-footer">
        <div id="unity-webgl-logo"></div>
        <div id="unity-fullscreen-button"></div>
        <div id="unity-build-title">My project (1)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
      var buildUrl = "Build";
      var loaderUrl = buildUrl + "/BuildWebGl3.loader.js";
      var config = {
        dataUrl: buildUrl + "/BuildWebGl3.data",
        frameworkUrl: buildUrl + "/BuildWebGl3.framework.js",
        codeUrl: buildUrl + "/BuildWebGl3.wasm",
        streamingAssetsUrl: "StreamingAssets",
        companyName: "DefaultCompany",
        productName: "My project (1)",
        productVersion: "1.0",
      };

      var container = document.querySelector("#unity-container");
      var canvas = document.querySelector("#unity-canvas");
      var loadingBar = document.querySelector("#unity-loading-bar");
      var progressBarFull = document.querySelector("#unity-progress-bar-full");
      var fullscreenButton = document.querySelector("#unity-fullscreen-button");
      var mobileWarning = document.querySelector("#unity-mobile-warning");

      if (/iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        container.className = "unity-mobile";
        config.devicePixelRatio = 1;
        mobileWarning.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(() => {
          mobileWarning.style.display = "none";
        }, 5000);
      } else {
        canvas.style.width = "960px";
        canvas.style.height = "600px";
      }
      loadingBar.style.display = "block";

      var script = document.createElement("script");
      script.src = loaderUrl;
      script.onload = () => {
        createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) => {
          progressBarFull.style.width = 100 * progress + "%";
        }).then((unityInstance) => {
          loadingBar.style.display = "none";
          fullscreenButton.onclick = () => {
            unityInstance.SetFullscreen(1);
          };
        }).catch((message) => {
          alert(message);
        });
      };
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Error:**

```
./src/UnityGames/BuildWebGl3/Build/BuildWebGl3.wasm
Module parse failed: magic header not detected 
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js      
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
Error: magic header not detected
```